# How to decrease the boldness of a text?

Tags: html, css

```css
#first {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 200;
}
#second {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 50;
}
#third {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p id="first">One account.All of google</p>
<p id="second">Sign in to continue to Gmail</p>
<div id="login">
  <form>
    <img src="img.jpg">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="Enter your username">
    <br>
    <input type="password" name="password" value="password">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Sign in">
    <br>
    <a href="">Forgot password?</a>
  </form>
</div>
<p id="third">Sign in with different account</p>
```

I'm unable to make the `font-weight` to decrease. I want the `#second` id to have lesser weight than the `#first` id one. I've used the `font-weight` but it still isn't working.

Comment: You want `#second` to have a weight of 100? Does the typeface you're using support that weight?

Comment: Individual fonts only support certain weights. Many fonts only support a weight of 700. Check the font you're using and make sure it supports the weights you're trying to use.

Comment: It's always a good practice to use `semi-bold` and `regular` versions of the font that you are using to get this different font-weight.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Font weights are **not** a dynamic thing. You can not arbitrarily decide to use a value and expect the font-weight to change. `font-weight: 50;` is *never* a correct property. No font contains a "50" weight.

A browser, or CSS, do **not** *create* font weights, or apply pseudo-weights (faux weight) to fonts with the only caveat being the `bold` designation -- browser may create a faux "bold" in some cases. The font file in use **must** posses the weight for the `font-weight` property to have effect. Browsers *may* guess and use the next closest weight. Sometimes a browser may guess adequately, sometimes they don't or there's nothing in the font file to use even if a guess is made.

There are two basic forms of font-weight --

Generic terms:

- `font-weight: normal;` - uses the standard weight of the font
- `font-weight: bold;` - uses the a weight of the font that is greater than "normal" **if the font contains this weight**
- `font-weight: bolder;` - uses a weight of the font that is greater than "normal" by 2x **if the font contains this weight**. Fallback is the use of the weight immediately greater than "normal" or "bold".
- `font-weight: lighter;` - uses a weight of the font that is less than "normal" **if the font contains this weight**. Fallback is the use of the "normal" weight.
- `font-weight: inherit;` -- Inherits the weight of the parent element
- `font-weight: initial;` -- uses the default weight of the font

And option two, specific weight designations. Note that the font file **must** be configured to contain these designations internally. You can't simply pick a number and use it.

- `font-weight: 100;` **if the font contains this weight**
- `font-weight: 200;` **if the font contains this weight**
- `font-weight: 300;` **if the font contains this weight**
- `font-weight: 400;` **if the font contains this weight**
- etc.

Setting `font-weight: 100;` to a font that does not contain the `100` weight designation simply means the browser will use the *next closest weight that **is** available*. So, if your font file only contains weights for 400, 600, and 900 -- if you set the weight to 100 and 200, then the 400 weight would be used in *both* instances because 400 is the closest value to 100 and 200. Setting the weight to 700 could mean the browser uses the 600 weight *or* the 900 weight. In most instances the lesser value is chosen, so most likely the 600 weight would be used.

If you want to use specific weights for a font family, you first need to ensure the font file itself contains that weight. Based on your posted markup, you need to use a font that *actually contains* the 200 and 100 weight designations.